# Can I create post request of Byte Array of a large video

Tags: javascript, arrays, video-streaming

I have a video of almost 300MBs and I want to send this video to server in form of byte array from javascript file.
Is there any solution available for this ?

And how much data should be send in one AJAX call so that it can work efficiently and can post data as soon as possible?

I have tried AJAX post request for this but it is showing 413 request entity too large error.

My variables are:

1. recorder.blob contains video data
2. ui8 contains video binary data
3. results contain char form of binary data

Here is my code for uploading where

```
var uri = URL.createObjectURL(recorder.blob), xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', uri, false);
xhr.send();
URL.revokeObjectURL(uri);
let ui8 = new Uint8Array(xhr.response.length);
let results;

for (i = 0; i < xhr.response.length; ++i) {
    ui8[i] = xhr.response.charCodeAt(i);
    results += String.fromCharCode(ui8[i]);
}

$.ajax({
    url: "http://p80ee.mocklab.io",
    type: 'post',
    data: ui8,
    success: function (result) {
        console.log("Response : " , result);
    }
});
```

Comment: how much data should be sent depends on how much data you need to send, whether you're worried about bandwidth/timeouts/network availability/server capacity/any specific limits placed by the server-side code etc etc etc.

Comment: as for the rest, you probably want to send a multi-part request, or maybe binary only if no other information needs to be transmitted at the same time. It'll be similar to uploading any other kind of (binary) file - plenty of examples of how to do that using JS available if you google it. AFAIK a video file is not special in that respect. Please show the code you've used so far. P.S. If your server supports it you may be able to upload the file in chunks to avoid size limitations etc.

Comment: Here's some [more info on your specific error](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=413+request+entity+too+large&oq=413+request+entity+too+large&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.335j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) - have you done any research yourself yet??

Comment: Yes, I researched a lot but I did not find any solution for my problem as I want to send byte array of my video to my mock server but it throws error of "Entity too large" but when I pass a string of one of two words, it reaches server easily

Comment: well "too large" seems pretty clear, even without googling it. The server won't let you send a file of that size. You'll have to split it up. Or, if it's your server application, change the settings to allow larger uploads.